# Number theory equality related to Möbius function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I proved this equality for $x>0$,
$$
2(e^x-1)e^{-2x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{\sinh nx}
$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function. The problem is my proof is not so elegant and I think I could improve it using a variation of Möbius inversion formula. I leave my proof.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{μ(n)}{\sinh (nx)} &= 2 \sum_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{μ(n)}{e^{nx} - e^{-nx}} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{μ(n)}{e^{nx}} \frac{1}{1-e^{-2nx}}\\
&= 2 \sum_{n=1}^{∞} μ(n) e^{-nx}(1+e^{-2nx}+e^{-4nx}+\dots)\\
& = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{∞} μ(n) \sum_{k=1}^{∞} e^{-(2k-1)nx}= 2 \sum_{n=1}^{∞} \sum_{k=1}^{∞} μ(n) e^{-(2k-1)nx}
\end{align*}
We know that series are absolutly convergent, so
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{μ(n)}{\sinh (nx)} = 2 \sum_{N=1}^{∞} e^{-Nx} \left(\sum_{n|N \text{ y }N/n\text{ is odd}} μ(n) \right)$$
If $N$ is odd
$$ \sum_{\substack{n|N \\ N/n\text{ is odd}}} μ(n) = \begin{cases}
 1, &\text{ si }N = 1\\
 0, &\text{ si }N > 1
\end{cases}$$
If $N$ is even and $N=2^am$
$$ \sum_{2^ak|2^am} μ(n) = \sum_{k|m} μ(2^a k) = \sum_{k|m} μ(2^a) μ(k) = \begin{cases}
 0, &\text{ si }a ≥ 2\\
 -1 &\text{ si }m=1\\
 0 &\text{ c.c.}
\end{cases}$$
Finally
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{μ(n)}{\sinh (nx)} = 2(e^{-x}-e^{-2x})$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453040/how-to-prove-that-2e-2xex-1-displaystyle-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mun?rq=1 Maybe this is what you want.

Comment: @See-WooLee Oh! Thank you, very much.